# React conditional rendering simplified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using react16 with Material-Ui components. On my root comp. I want to load a tab and a view conditionally on a property. I managed to get this functionality done. But the code looks really ugly and maybe this can be simplified. The condition depends on `this.props.isSIInstalled`

#### Component:

```
  render() {
    const {shouldSwipe} = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Tabs className=' electric' value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} variant="scrollable" id={'tabMenu'}>

            <Tab label={1} value={0}/>
            <Tab label={2} value={1}/>
            <Tab label={3} value={2}/>
            {this.props.isSIInstalled
            && <Tab label={4} value={3}/>}
          </Tabs>
          {
            this.props.isSIInstalled ?
          <SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)} disabled={!shouldSwipe}>

              <div>Item One</div>
              <div>Item Two</div>
              <div>Item Three</div>
              <div>Item Four</div>

          </SwipeableViews> :
              <SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)} disabled={!shouldSwipe}>

              <div>Item One</div>
              <div>Item Two</div>
              <div>Item Three</div>

              </SwipeableViews>
            }
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall what I've done is using the map function which is a lifesaver on React and moved some strings to another file, makes the code more neat and readable.

```
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="noScroll">
        <Tabs className='byod-no-pinch-zoom electric' value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} variant="scrollable" id={'tabMenu'}>

          TAB_INFO.map(x => <Tab label={x.label} id={x.id} />)
          {this.props.isSIInstalled
            && <Tab label={getSID('SID_RHMI_BYOD_SOURCE_EXPERIENCES')} value={3} />}
        </Tabs>
        {
          this.props.isSIInstalled ?
            <SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)} disabled={!shouldSwipe}>
              <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
                <JourneyInfo webSocketClient={this.props.webSocketClient} />
              </div>

              ['Item Two','Item Three','Item Four'].map( x=>
                <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
                <div>{x}</div>
              </div>
              )
            </SwipeableViews> :
            <SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)} disabled={!shouldSwipe}>
              <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
                <JourneyInfo webSocketClient={this.props.webSocketClient} />
              </div>
              <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom" />
              <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom" />
            </SwipeableViews>
        }
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Another file, usually called strings.js or constants.

```
const export TAB_INFO = [
  {
    label: 'SID_RHMI_BYOD_INFO',
    value: 0,
  },
  {
    label: 'SID_RHMI_BYOD_MEDIA',
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    label: 'SID_RHMI_BYOD_CLIMATE',
    value: 2,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your conditional components are almost the same, and the only difference is that you show/hide *ItemFour* depends on this.props.isSIInstalled. So you can simplify code as:

```
 ...
 </Tabs>
<SwipeableViews index={this.state.value} onChangeIndex={this.handleChange.bind(this)} disabled={!shouldSwipe}>
            <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
              <div>Item One</div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
              <div>Item Two</div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
              <div>Item Three</div>
            </div>
            {
                  this.props.isSIInstalled && (
                       <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
                          <div>Item Four</div>
                       </div>
                  )
            }
          </SwipeableViews>
```

Also, if you'd like to render absolutely different views base on condition, you can do following:

```
</Tabs>
{
     this.props.isSIInstalled && View1
}
{
    !this.props.isSIInstalled && View2
}
```

Comment: Yeah u are right the only difference is loading a fourth view. I thought of your approach too. But it throws me the error: ` Warning: react-swipeable-view: one of the children provided is invalid: null.We are expecting a valid React Element`

Comment: Well that might be an ugly hack, but you can try

 `{
                  this.props.isSIInstalled ?  (
                       <div className="modal-container byod-no-pinch-zoom">
                          <div>Item Four</div>
                       </div>
                  ) : ''
            }` - return an empty string if you don't need to render this element

Comment: Also you can describe an array of all views : 
views = [{component: View1}, {component: View2, isHidden: !this.props.isSIInstalled}]. And create  SwipeableViews's children like `views.filter(view => !view.isHidden).map(view => view.component)`. This way you'll receive only valid ReactNodes